# How do I tell my program to go back to a certain point after the wrong answer is selected?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, control-flow

In my midterm CYA game, you come across 2 staircases, left and right. You have the option to choose which one you go to, the right advancing you and the left (eventually) sending you back because it is blocked. I don't know how to get it to do that based on what I already have.

```
    List<string> itemsList1 = new List<string>();

    
    string input1;
    string input2;
    public FirstSteps()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately for us, we have to start at the bottom of the castle, unless you have a catapult or a grappling hook, but I don't suppose you have either of those do you.\n");
        

    }
    
    public void Populate()
    {
        contentArray1[0] = "See that key lying there? Think we should grab it?\n Type Yes or No.";
        contentArray1[1] = "Really? You don't want to grab the key thats just sitting there? Your loss.";
        contentArray1[2] = "Wow, isn't this a cliche. 2 staircases, the wrtiers really must be getting bored. Anyways, we going for the right or the left?\n Type Right or Left";
        contentArray1[3] = "This staircase is blocked, try again";
        contentArray1[4] = "Theres a chest up here, wonder if that key can open it, wanna try?\n Type Yes or No.";
        contentArray1[5] = "You need the key to open the chest, duh.";
    }

    public void KeyEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(contentArray1[0]);
        input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        input1 = input1.ToLower();

        if (input1 == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Right, probably a good idea.");
            itemsList1.Add("dirty key");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(contentArray1[1]);
        }
                       
    }

    public void StepsEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(contentArray1[2]);
        input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        input2 = input2.ToLower();

        if (input2 == "left")
        {
           
            Console.WriteLine(contentArray1[3]);
        }
        if (input2 == "right")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Right one it is.");
            Console.WriteLine(contentArray1[4]);
        }
    }
```

This is (most of) my class that I am working with. When I begin working with input2 is where the problem arises, based on what I have set up with the array and the if statements I don't know how to make it so when the left if statemnt triggers, it says contentArray1[3], and then sends you back to the decision. I imagine I need a loop but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: The whole thing could go into a loop. The pattern for these types of problems is `while(!escape_condition) { AskQuestion(); ReadAnswer(); EvaluateEscapeCondition(); }`

Comment: Slightly off-topic note: always prepare for the smart players who literally answer your question by typing "Right or Left" instead of your expected input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `go to` statement.

PC: Very easy to use.

[About `go to`](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hirendra_singh/goto-statement-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: You can use Goto. But there is always a better solution.

Comment: 'Go to' not recommended, but in this case I think normal.